# Connect VS2022 debugger to ASP.NET Core application hosted on windows server IIS (2019)

Tags: asp.net-core, ocr, remote-debugging, syncfusion

I'm having issues with ASP.NET Core 6 app on my VPN Windows server 2019. Basically, I have Syncfusion `OCRProcessor` with tesseract files, but my application can't find part of the path for tesseract binaries on server when locally is working fine (on server error message is "cannot find part of the path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\x64").

After contacting Syncfusion support didn't solve the issue, I have checked for permissions in file system, double checked the locations of the binaries on IIS, checked if dll's are blocked in from Windows in file system. I have tried to connect from my machine with VS 2022 Community to my VPN server (public IP address) to try to debug the application, but going trough all the documents about remote debugging, still I can't connect to my app and hit the breakpoint in code to determine what is happening..

I have installed remote debugger for VS 2022 onto server, configure it and started, I have published application again over web deploy with debug config to IIS, but I just don't understand next step - how to attach to the process on external server..

Most of the videos and documentation suggests that IIS is installed locally on development machine, or IIS is on some PC in local network, but I have public server.. Can anyone help with the advice how to proceed further?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have managed to connect debugger from VS 2022 to IIS.

The issue was in port, firewall and also in description on Microsoft help site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2022 where in step 3 is written "Set the Qualifier field to  and press Enter." - you need to enter ip address and port into connection target textbox.

After succesfull logging in onto server, I needed to select w3wp.exe process with title "CoreApp: https://.. ", set breakpoint in VS 2022 and open ASP.NET Core app in browser. After that I managed to debug application on IIS.

Hope this would be helpful to someone!